# Razor and Antiforgery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, csrf

I recently came accros the following note on the Microsoft doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery):

> Razor Pages are automatically protected from XSRF/CSRF. You don't have to write any additional code. See XSRF/CSRF and Razor Pages for more information.

Pointing to this other page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/index?tabs=visual-studio#xsrf) where it says:

> You don't have to write any code for antiforgery validation. Antiforgery token generation and validation are automatically included in Razor Pages.

I use Razor with my ASP.NET MVC application and also protect my forms with the AntiForgeryToken helpers. Because of the way the Antiforgery tokens are validated against each other (hidden field + cookie), my users **must** allow cookies on the website.

I am now confused with what I read in the doc as it seems to say that I don't need to use the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` helper or the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute when using Razor...?

As an additional question, is there a way to protect my site against CSRF attack without using the cookies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the first link in the post (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery) I've found the explanation:

> ASP.NET Core implements anti-request-forgery using the ASP.NET Core
>   data protection stack.
>
> In ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 the FormTagHelper injects anti-forgery tokens
>   for HTML form elements.

For older versions of ASP.NET MVC, the helpers you mention are needed.

Comment: Thanks @dexter, I went back and forth multiple times on the Microsoft website and obviously didn't realise I had switched to ASP.NET Core...
The 'classic' ASP.NET MVC doc can be found there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages#generating-the-tokens